# Which one is correct? Average CPU usage in resource monitor or CPU usage in task manager?

Tags: windows-10, cpu, cpu-usage, c

I have a C program which I'm running in windows 10 and I need to know how much CPU it uses. When I run the program, the windows 10 task manager says the program is consuming 25% of the CPU. Although at the same time I checked the CPU usage of that program in resource monitor, it shows more than 80% cpu usage:

Task manager:

[image]

Resource monitor:

[image]

So which one is correct? How much cpu I'm consuming and why are these numbers so different?

P.S.
My CPU: Intel(R) core(TM) i7. Also the program runs for a few minutes not just seconds.

Comment: Let Resource Monitor run for 15 minutes and see what the value is after this. The graph shows an average total, but the line in the CPU window for the process is point in time. I suspect you saw Task Manager at a different point than Resource Monitor - that's all.

Comment: @John Thanks John but no, I run it in a loop for a long time, and the numbers are steady in a way I mentioned. There is no peak in task manager and there is no falling in the resource monitor's numbers.

Comment: I am not sure because I do not know the process or how it is running in Windows. I always assume Task Manager to be correct.